# jinja2 template syntax in Homeassistant

Tags: jinja2

The code below consist of .yaml template language.

I have a question which is "float -2" in Jinja2 template source.

I can't understand it.

Does it means simply "result value minus 2" nor "result value rounds as -2 digit"?

Please answer to me if someone learned well about Jinja2 template exist.

```
- id: miair2_auto_stop_window
  alias: 'Mi Air Pro2 Auto Stop in Window'
  trigger:
    platform: template
    value_template: "{{ states.fan.xiaomi_air_pro_2_window.attributes.aqi | float < states.input_number.miair2_stop_window.state | float -2 }}"
  condition:
    condition: state
    entity_id: input_select.miair2_am_window
    state: 'Auto'
  action:
    service: fan.turn_off
    entity_id: fan.xiaomi_air_pro_2_window
```

Comment: There is no such thinga `.yaml` template language. There are templates that might expand to YAML, but that has nothing to do with YAML per se (nor with Python). If you can't understand something, there is no use in asking: no answers can make you understand it (Did you mean: "I don't understand ..." )?

Answer (score 0):

float is a filter to convert the value on the left side to a float. The -2 is the default value in case the conversion for some reason fails.

See http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#builtin-filters for description of the built in filters to jinja.